# The distance between two opposite vertices of the dodecagon is 2. Find the area of the dodecagon.

Tags: geometry, polygons

The distance between two opposite vertices of a regular dodecagon is 2. Find the area of the dodecagon.

I drew a diagram but I don't have any ideas.  Any help?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean a *regular* dodecagon?

Comment: Nope, just a dodecagon.

Comment: Then the area can be anything between $0$ and the area of the regular dodecagon inscribed in a circle of radius $1$.

Comment: Okay, I just noticed that the problem was attached to another problem.  So I think it is a regular dodecagon.  Thanks for catching that!

Comment: A regular dodecagon is made up of 12 congruent isosceles triangles. You know the equal sides and angle between them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The area of a regular dodecagon is just three times the square of its circumradius:

[image]

So a regular dodecagon with diameter $2$ has area $\color{red}{\large 3}$.

Here it is a non-animated but colorful dissection:

[image]

Comment: Can you use different colors for the three different sets of moving parts that come together in the different squares?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: yes, but that will take some time. I linked a gif I made a while ago and I am not sure to still have the original Geogebra file. Please be patient.

Comment: Whoa!  That really explains everything!  Thanks for your answer, Jack D'Aurizio!

Answer (score 4):

Divide the regular dodecagon into twelve triangles by drawing line segments from the vertices to the center.  Each triangle has two sides of length $1$ and the included angle between these sides measures $30°$.

Let $O$ be the center of the dodecagon and $A, B, C$ be three consecutive vertices.  Draw diagonal $AC$ which subtends a central angle of $60°$.  Triangle $OAC$ is isosceles with its base angle equal to that subtended $60°$ central angle, thus equilateral so $AC=OA=OC=1$.  At the same time $OB$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$ so the altitude of triangle $OAB$ to side $OB$ is $AC/2=1/2$.  Then the area of the triangle is $(1/2)\times(1)\times(1/2)=1/4$.  With twelve such triangles we get the full dodecagon having an area of $3$ square units.

Comment: seems you forgot "sine of"

Comment: Yup.  Busted!  Thanks.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  I have not learned sines and cosines yet, could you include a solution without using advanced geometry?  Thanks!

Comment: That seems strange.  If I call  the center $O$ and three consecutive vertices $A, B, C$, can I assume that $OB$ is the perpendicular bisector of $AC$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi  Yes.  Now where to go on from there?